# Json string to Java object Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json string in this format :

```
 [
   {
     "key1": { "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" },
     "key2": { "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" }
   }
]
```

To parse it I created a java class :

```
class data {
     String key;
     List <content> listdata;
     /* getter and setter for the attribute above */
     ...
   }
```

Now I followed Gson documentation, and try to exract data :

```
Gson gson =new Gson();
data[] ints = gson.fromJson(MyjsonString, data[].class);
```

I get parsing error from Gson API, what I done wrong ?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path
```

Comment: Are you sure, your data should not look like this? `[ {
     "key": [ "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" ]}, {
     "key": [ "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" ]}]`

Comment: No its like what i presented above

Answer (score 1):

For parsing `json` like following class

```
class data {
String key;
List <content> listdata;
/* getter and setter for the attribute above */
...
}
```

you need a `json` like as follows

```
"data" : {
 "key": "value",
 "listdata": [{ content object key attributes here }]
}
```

As your exception clearly saying `BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING` so you have to use array in `json` for parsing.

**In Reply of your comment**

If you want a class which parse following json

```
{
 "key1": { "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" },
 "key2": { "key1":"val1","key2":"val2" }
}
```

Then you would have classes structure as follows

```
class Data {
 Map<String, String> key1;
 Map<String, String> key2;
 /* getter and setter for the attribute above */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i know that i have to change my class structure but, can you suggest me a new one ?

Comment: I can't so change my Json String, but i can change my java class to suite the requirement.

Comment: You have changed the message structure with this { key:{ content }, key2: {conetent }}, but how we can do it without omit [], i mean to save the message like this [{{},{}}] ?

Comment: well, then you can use Map<String, String> key1 and Map<String, String> key2 in Data class this is very easy to use. also see my updated answer!

Comment: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path

Answer (score 0):

As per the Json, this class structure works:

```
class data {
 List <Map<String,Content> data;
 /* getter and setter for the attribute above */
 ...
```

}

Comment: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected ':' at line 1 column 9 path

Comment: something is wrong with the json, check your json, you could use jsonlint.com

Comment: i tested it in this link its a valid json